# Bugreport: Impossible to create more than 25 events

Tags: civievent, issues

I tried to create events. For the first 25 events it worked fine, after 25 events, I got an access denied error instead of the event configuration page:

> "Entschuldigung, eine Bereitstellung ist uns gerade nicht möglich. Sie
>   haben nicht die notwendigen Berechtigungen, um diese Seite
>   aufzurufen."

The event is created in the database table civicrm_event but not shown in the event overview in civicrm. If I delete some rows in the sql database civicrm_event, I can create events again up to 25.

I turned on the debug mode. I think, this query is the problem:

> CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') :
>   database_ in options CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SELECT a.id as `id`, a.title
>   as `title` FROM civicrm_event a LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
>
> CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.000273 seconds. Result is 25 rows
>   by 2 columns.

So the resultset has only the first 25 rows and the created event isn't in the resultset.

I use civicrm 4.7.19 with drupal 7.54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you apply the patch here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325 There is a default limit on API calls to 25 records which is what your probably hitting here

Seamus