# Can't create more than 26 events in CiviEvents (or view on dashboard)

Tags: civievent, joomla

No matter what I do, I can't create more than 26 events in CiviEvent. It seems this might have happened in the latest CiviCRM update because I already have more than 26 events, but only 26 are visible in the dashboard.

I created a fresh install of Joomla 3.7.2 and CiviCRM 4.17.19, then imported in my civicrm_event table with around 100 events and the problem still exists.

I removed all the events from the table except 25 of them. Then I was able to create one more event. After that, I only got this error when trying to create or duplicate an event:

[Permission error trying to create new event or copy existing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/permission-error-trying-to-create-new-event-or-copy-existing)

If I delete an event, I can create a new one up to 26 (no matter the ID). If I import 100 events into the civicrm_event table, only 26 of them will appear on the dashboard. If I delete one of the visible events, one of the "invisible" ones will appear.

I have a test site set up and can share access if someone can take a look at it.

Comment: See the answer at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/bugreport-impossible-to-create-more-than-25-events

Answer (score 4):

This answer is from @SeamusLee at [Bugreport: Impossible to create more than 25 events](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/bugreport-impossible-to-create-more-than-25-events)

"I would recommend you apply the patch here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325 There is a default limit on API calls to 25 records which is what your probably hitting here

Seamus"